# String operations printing random character on Serial Monitor

Tags: arduino-ide, esp32, c-string

I want to extract the file name `MyFile.txt` out of a path which is stored in a string `"C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.txt";`

I found a simple [c code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520560/get-a-file-name-from-a-path?answertab=votes#tab-top?#answer-8520815) which does the job.

```
string filename = "C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat";

// Remove directory if present.
// Do this before extension removal incase directory has a period character.
const size_t last_slash_idx = filename.find_last_of("\\/");
if (std::string::npos != last_slash_idx)
{
    filename.erase(0, last_slash_idx + 1);
}

// Remove extension if present.
const size_t period_idx = filename.rfind('.');
if (std::string::npos != period_idx)
{
    filename.erase(period_idx);
}
```

I had to alter few things for arduino code
example replace `find_last_of` with `lastIndexOf`, `erase` with `remove` and `rfind` with `lastIndexOf`

Here the `ino` file

```
#include<string>
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);

}

void loop() {   
   String filename = "C:\MyDirectory\MyFile.bat";

// Remove directory if present.
// Do this before extension removal incase directory has a period character.
const size_t last_slash_idx = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
if (std::string::npos != last_slash_idx)
{
    filename.remove(0, last_slash_idx + 1);
}

// Remove extension if present.
const size_t period_idx = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
if (std::string::npos != period_idx)
{
    filename.remove(period_idx);
}  
Serial.println(filename);
delay(1000);
}
```

Expected output `MyFile`

When I look into Serial Monitor I get

```
c$$⸮'<;⸮⸮/<⸮⸮$⸮''⸮;,#$$⸮'<;⸮⸮'<⸮⸮$⸮''⸮:$#$$⸮'<;⸮⸮'<⸮⸮$⸮''⸮;$#$$⸮'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you choose 9600 baud in the serial monitor?

Comment: Yes this was on `9600`

Answer (score 1):

> ```cpp
> #include<string>
> ```

Remove this. Arduino uses its own `String` class, different from the STL
`string`.

> ```cpp
> String filename = "C:\MyDirectory\MyFile.bat";
> ```

There is no `'\M'` escape sequence in C++ strings. You probably mean
`"C:\\MyDirectory\\MyFile.bat"`.

> ```cpp
> const size_t last_slash_idx = filename.lastIndexOf("\\");
> ```

`String::lastIndexOf()` returns an `int`, not `size_t`.

> ```cpp
> if (std::string::npos != last_slash_idx)
> ```

No `std::string` here. `String::lastIndexOf()` returns `-1` to signify
that the character was not found.

With all these fixes, your sketch should work as intended.